how to extract images from IBM Content manager OSM_32K_OBJ_TBL table?
Following is table schema
OTVER   CHAR
OTSEG   SMALLINT
OTCLID  INTEGER
OTNAME  VARCHAR
OTOBJ   LONGVAR
Can we extract image from this backend table ?
I am trying to extract all images from backend from IBM content manager as part of migration.

Consider editing your question to add the following facts (do not use comments because they are not searchable)  (1) What is the server platform for Content-Manager (z/os, i-series (as400), or linux/unix/windows?   (2) What is the Content-manager version exactly?  (3) What is your toolset?
